# Is ASP.NET with .NET 4 faster

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I'm looking to upgrade my ASP.NET web app to the .NET 4 framework.  Would I see performance improvements right away?

Comment: I'd expect performance to be approximately equal to before. What kind of performance improvements do you expect?

Comment: I don't know what to expect, hence the question.

Comment: These types of questions are extremely difficult to answer. No comparisons have been done (that i know of) of ASP.NET 4 vs ASP.NET 3.5 (for example). Most things to improve "speed" (again, another issue - page load time? CLR compile time?), can apply to both versions, like reducing ViewState, reducing round-trips to DB, minimizing HTTP requests, etc. These are general practices, not ASP.NET 4 specific. Perhaps you can mention what areas you are wanting to see improvement?

Comment: @RPM1984: Not to sound rude but my question is very simple and straightforward.  To answer your question, I'm looking for any area that would gain *instant*, as in not changing any code, performance improvements.

Comment: Yes, you would...in certain areas.  OK, next question...

Comment: @rball: Your comment is not helpful.  Please be courteous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/571334.aspx), there are supposed to be internal runtime improvements that should help out of the box.

> According to Microsoft, there have
>   also been a number of invisible
>   performance improvements in the
>   internals of the ASP.NET runtime that
>   should make ASP.NET 4.0 applications
>   run more efficiently and use less
>   resources. These features come without
>   any change requirements in
>   applications and are virtually
>   transparent, except that you get the
>   benefits by updating to ASP.NET 4.0.

There is a PDC presentation (which I cannot currently find) that claimed the same thing. I would assume that YMMV depending on your implementation, in any case.

Obviously ASP.Net 4.0 will benefit from any areas of the .Net 4.0 runtime on which it depends that are improved.  It's **usually** safe to assume that a new release will make things no worse...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the performance improvement is probably in development. A lot of things have been improved like handling of ID's so Javascript can interact better with controls. And some C#4.0 features like the dynamic object and it late binding. Here is a list of all the benefits ASP.NET 4.0 Have:

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4